# Trying to bind data from sql query to view for a dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, knockout.js

My sample code are like this :

Model which hold list Items:

```
public IList<ListItem> ListOfRecords { get; set; }
```

Populating the model in controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new ViewModel();
    model.ListOfEmployees = GetAllRecordsFromDataBase();
    return View(model);
}
```

My View:

```
<select data-bind="options: optionValues, selectedOptions: SelectedOptionValues"></select>
```

Knockout Code for Populating the dropdown:

```
function DoNotCallModel(optionValues, SelectedOptionValues) {
var self = this;
self.optionValues = ko.observableArray(optionValues); 
self.SelectedOptionValues = ko.observable(SelectedOptionValues);
return self; 
}



@foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <text>
                model.ContactUsers.push(new ContactModel('@item.Id',
            '@HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(item.InsertRequestedByEmployee)',
            '@HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(item.PhoneNumber)',
            '@HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(item.EmailAddress)',
            '@HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(item.Notes)',
            '@HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(item.InsertedBy)',
            '@item.InsertDate'
              ))
            </text>
            }
            window.model = model;
            ko.applyBindings(model);
```

Am not sure how to populate the data in my model into this dropdown. I have done data-binding using knockout for input type. First time trying dropdown.

Comment: Is that the entire view? Where is the model populated in to it?

Comment: No this is only part of the view, my view code is a bit longer. I will try to complete it. I have a save and delete function which either adds a row or deletes a row.

Comment: function DoNotCallModel(optionValues, SelectedOptionValues) {
    var self = this;
    self.optionValues = ko.observableArray(optionValues); 
    self.SelectedOptionValues = ko.observable(SelectedOptionValues);
return self;  }

Comment: Just [edit] the question.

Comment: Edited and added few more lines to make it look complete. Basically am populating a table, where one of the columns needs to be a dropdown. I have populated and everything else is working except this dropdown thing. I just need to populate a dropdown, on selecting a value, and clicking save i need to save the record back to db.

Comment: If you are using selectedOptions I'm assuming you want a multi select. In that case the SelectedOptionValues should also be an observableArray instead of an observable.

Comment: No multi select, Just one value

Answer (score 0):

You need several more bindings, assuming you're trying to bind a complex object to the drop down.

optionsText - defines what text to show

optionsValue - what the value of the selected option should be

value - the value of the dropdown once an option is selected (separate observable in viewmodel)

```
//Contract type collection
self.ContractTypes = ko.observableArray();

//ContractType object
self.ContractType = function (data) {
    this.ContractType = ko.observable(data.ContractType);
    this.ContractTypeId = ko.observable(data.ContractTypeID);
};

//Value of selected contract type
self.SelectedContractType = ko.observable();

<select data-bind="options: ContractTypes, optionsText: 'ContractType', optionsValue: 'ContractTypeId', value: SelectedContractType></select>
```

Your binding stuff is for multiple options to be selected at the same time.